# How to get current user login details in joomla

Tags: joomla2.5

I have one doubt in Joomla. I can able to get the user login details while I am accessing the index.php...Whereas if i created new folder named test and inside the folder i have created index.php and i have used below code in that case user details were not showing. Please help me on this

```
$user =& JFactory::getUser();

if (!$user->guest) {
  echo 'You are logged in as:<br />';
  echo 'User name: ' . $user->username . '<br />';
  echo 'Real name: ' . $user->name . '<br />';
  echo 'User ID  : ' . $user->id . '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand the problem is you can access Joomla function within it's scope. Other words you can not access Joomla core function if the framework is not included in the page you are running.

To access the core functions outside of Joomla include the framework to do so. Please google and see how it should be done.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..Even if i have include all the related files i am getting error as  "No configuration file found and no installation code available. Exiting..." Please help

Comment: search the error on google and see. There are a lot of guidance

Comment: Sounds like you did more than initialize the framework. What code did you use?

Comment: Since you are new here, accept the answer(tick) which solved your problem. Up-vote(up arrow) the answer(s) which give(s) you information or help(s) you. Down-vote(down arrow) the answer(s) which are fake.

Answer (score 2):

This should be enough to get the framework loaded so you can use Joomla classes and access the user object:

```
<?php
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
// JPATH_BASE should point to Joomla!'s root directory
define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) .'/' ) );
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
$session =& JFactory::getSession();
?>
```